# How to filter packet on wireshark

Tags: wireshark-dissector

How to filter the packets from specific host name and port on wireshark. I'm looking for the syntax to do a capture filter on WireShark, by capturing the traffic on several (specific) IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this capture filter:

```
host 192.168.1.2 or 192.168.1.3 or 192.168.1.4
```

Type this command in capture->option->capture filter